# Switch employers easily before moving to Berlin?

Tags: working-visas, relocation

I'm moving to Berlin for work in November and I have a single question I'd like answered. I've never lived in Europe.

My biggest question is this: I was hired by a company, after a long and painful process, I got my work permit. Everything seemed to be ok. After all the process. Several changes agreed between me and company happened and I was upset and suspicious, but even so I decide to go.

What happens that I get a better job offer from a different company. I am really excited with opportunity and would like to accept.

I am in my country yet.

I would like to ask what the best way to process with my visa.

- Can I just notice the first company e accept the new contract and use the visa for the new company?
- I will need a new visa and new process?

Comment: It depends. There are different type of work visas and they can come with a mention restricting your ability to switch employers, you can't assume that you will be able to take any other job, or to do it without any formality.

Answer (score 1):

I got my problem solved.

- Just notice the company
- Go to embassy again and start a new visa process, they will cancel you first visa and issue again :).